# Making Log In as default page on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to make my login as the default page before the user accesses the home page. This is my code.

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
           <clear/>
           <add value="Login.aspx"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is first establish the authorization and authentication mechanism. You can use `FormsAuthentication` and configure the settings in a `web.config` file. For example, to enable forms authentication you would set the following value in the config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms 
      name=".ASPXAUTH" 
      loginUrl="login.aspx" 
      defaultUrl="default.aspx" 
      protection="All" 
      timeout="30" 
      path="/" 
      requireSSL="false" 
      slidingExpiration="true" 
      cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain="" 
      enableCrossAppRedirects="false">
      <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />
   </forms>
   <passport redirectUrl="internal" />
</authentication>
```

Here you can see that `loginUrl` is set to **login.aspx**. This way, if a user is not authenticated, he or she will be redirected to **login.aspx**

This is much better approach than establishing your own logic for redirection to login or setting login.aspx as a start page.

Comment: but how had you guessed that OP has implemented Form Authentication ??

Comment: @Dhaval, What is OP? I don't quiet understand your question.

Comment: OP means Original Poster or questioner

Comment: It's my suggestion. Instead of doing the plumbing, Jef can use what already exists and avoid the hard work. That is the point of my answer.

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic it worked! Thank you for helping me. It's for my thesis. God bless, sir.

Comment: One more thing, where can I download MS SQL server express 2008 for my database? Link please. Having a hard time downloading it. Ugh.

Comment: This is the link to [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23650).

Answer (score 2):

just Right click on that page and click on set as start up page.